# I can't execute the SqlCommand

Tags: c#, database, sqlcommand, executenonquery

hello guys I have got this code

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = baglanti;

cmd.CommandText = "(musteriadi,musterisoyadi,gsm,email,sirketadi,Adres,Notlar) VALUES('" + txtMusteriAdi.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtMusteriSoyadi.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtGsm.Text.Trim() + "','" +txtEmail.Text.Trim() + "','" +txtSirketAdi.Text.Trim() + "','" +txtAdres.Text.Trim() + "','" +txtNotlar.Text.Trim() +"');";
baglanti.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

baglanti.Close();
```

I defined the cmd as a `public SqlCommmand` and in every time when the code come to the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` it falls to catch what can I do .

Comment: "it falls to catch what can I do"? DO you get an exception? If so what is it?

Comment: Next time, please consider to be more clear about the _it falls_ part. Explain what do you mean by that. Put your error or exception message if you get one. Be clear as much as you can. Take a look at [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Answer (score 7):

Because you forget [`INSERT INTO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) part for your statement. Like;

```
INSERT INTO tableName(musteriadi,musterisoyadi,gsm,email,sirketadi,Adres,Notlar)
```

But much more important, you should *always* use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command *automatically* instead of calling `Close` method manually.

```
using(var baglanti = new SqlConnnection(yourConnectionString))
using(var cmd = baglanti.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO tableName(musteriadi,musterisoyadi,gsm,email,sirketadi,Adres,Notlar)
                        VALUES(@ad, @soyad, @gsm, @email, @sirket, @adres, @notlar)";
    // Add your parameters values with Add method considering their types and size.
    baglanti.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: It's still falling the catch exeption when it come to executenonquery :(

Comment: @alidurgun Are you _really_ sure you add your parameter values properly? Do you get any exception or error message? Please share this kind of information.

Comment: I have posted can you check this code please

Comment: @alidurgun `edit` in your question, don't post as an answer.